# Iterative plotting time series using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I have the following time series data (only samlpe given here):

```
df
        Month repo revrepo bankrate  CRR Callrate  WPI GDP  FED width    nse   usd
1  2001-04-01 9.00    6.75      7.0 8.00     7.49 5.41 4.6 4.50   225 1125.2 46.79
2  2001-05-01 8.75    6.50      7.0 7.50     8.03 5.60 4.6 4.00   225 1167.9 46.92
3  2001-06-01 8.50    6.50      7.0 7.50     7.24 5.30 4.6 3.75   200 1107.9 47.00
4  2001-07-01 8.50    6.50      7.0 7.50     7.19 5.23 5.3 3.75   200 1072.8 47.14
5  2001-08-01 8.50    6.50      7.0 7.50     6.94 5.41 5.3 3.50   200 1053.8 47.13
6  2001-09-01 8.50    6.50      7.0 7.50     7.30 4.52 5.3 3.00   200  913.9 47.65
7  2001-10-01 8.50    6.50      6.5 7.50     7.40 2.91 6.8 2.50   200  971.9 48.02
8  2001-11-01 8.50    6.50      6.5 5.75     6.97 2.59 6.8 2.00   200 1067.2 48.00
9  2001-12-01 8.50    6.50      6.5 5.50     7.08 2.08 6.8 1.75   200 1059.0 47.92
10 2002-01-01 8.50    6.50      6.5 5.50     6.63 1.51 6.4 1.75   200 1075.4 48.32
11 2002-02-01 8.50    6.50      6.5 5.50     6.73 1.39 6.4 1.75   200 1142.0 48.69
12 2002-03-01 8.00    6.00      6.5 5.50     6.97 1.76 6.4 1.75   200 1129.5 48.74
13 2002-04-01 8.00    6.00      6.5 5.50     6.58 1.50 5.1 1.75   200 1084.5 48.92
14 2002-05-01 8.00    6.00      6.5 5.50     6.90 1.56 5.1 1.75   200 1028.8 49.00
15 2002-06-01 8.00    5.75      6.5 5.00     6.04 2.43 5.1 1.75   225 1057.8 48.97
```

I am trying to plot each variable using ggplot as shown below (only first variable plot shown as example):

```
ts_data<-df
ts_data$Month<-as.Date(ts_data$Month,"%Y-%m-%d")

library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = ts_data, aes(x=Month, y=repo, color = "repo"),size=1.45,colour="#0072B2")  +ylim(0,12) +labs(color="") + xlab('\nYears') + ylab('Repo Rates (%)\n') + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 year",date_labels = "%Y")+ggtitle("Repo Rate movement from 2001 April to 2016 April") + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=12, color = "black")) + theme_stata() 
p
```

[image]

I can similarly plot all the other remaining variables but to be efficient, one can go for iterative method. How can i plot all the variables iteratively with the plot title as well as yaxis title changing with each iteration. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reshape from wide to long format, then use facets, no need for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop through columns and output as PDF, each column plotted as a new page:

```
# if Month column is not date class then convert to date
# df1$Month <- as.Date(df1$Month, "%Y-%m-%d")

pdf("myPlots.pdf")
for(i in tail(colnames(df1), -1)){
  gg <- ggplot(df1, aes_string(x = "Month", y = i)) +
    geom_line() + ggtitle(paste("My title for", i))
  print(gg)}
dev.off()
```

Or we can reshape from wide-to-long format, then use *facet_*

```
library(tidyr) 

plotDat <- gather(df1, key = "Group", value = "Y", -Month)

ggplot(plotDat, aes(x = Month, y = Y)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(Group ~ ., scales = "free_y")
```

Comment: Suppose i want append the units iteratively say % or some thing else to the Yaxis title.Can it be done? I have prepared a vector and want these units to be appended to the y axis title: units<-c("%","%","%","%","%","%","%","%","bps","index points","Rs")

Comment: @Nishant Avoid asking new questions. We could do something like: `ggtitle(paste("My title for", i, "units", ifelse(i %in% c("repo", "revrepo", "bankrate"), "%", "other")))`

Answer (score 0):

assuming you read from a csv file:

```
library(lubridate)
library(reshape2)
library(dply)

    # If your 'Month' variable is already of Date class ignore the following line
df$Month<-ymd(df$Month)


dfmelt=melt(df,id.vars="Month")
ggplot(dfmelt,aes(x=Month,y=value,col=variable))+geom_line()
```

Comment: This plots all the series in one plot frame which distorts the y limits as nse variable is in thousands and the rest are in single digits.Maybe some sort of scaling will be required here.Wanted individual plots but using iterations like using for or lapply. Anyways thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the answer given by @ zx8754, here is the final code with the required theme:

```
       for(i in tail(colnames(ts_data), -1)){
  gg <- ggplot(ts_data, aes_string(x = "Month", y = i)) +
    geom_line(size=1.45,colour="#0072B2") + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 year",date_labels = "%Y")+ xlab('\nYear') + ylab(paste(i,ifelse(i %in% c("repo", "revrepo", "bankrate","CRR","Callrate","WPI", "GDP","FED"), "(%)", ifelse(i %in% c("width"),"(bps)",ifelse(i %in% c("nse"),"(index points)","(Rs.)"))),'\n')) + ggtitle(paste(i,"Trend from 2001 April to 2016 April\n")) + theme_stata()
  print(gg)
  }
```

Thanx a lot. Facet grid compresses the plots as there are many series, otherwise that was also an excellent solution. Maybe some sort of facet wrap can be used here.Learnt a lot!